# Postgres highload. 20000 requests per min causes resource request timed out

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres 9.6.2 on my server with the following config:

```
application_name    phpPgAdmin_5.1
bytea_output    escape
client_encoding UTF8
cluster_name    9.6/main
DateStyle   ISO, MDY
default_text_search_config  en
dynamic_shared_memory_type  posix
effective_io_concurrency    4
external_pid_file   /var/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pid
lc_messages en_US.UTF-8
lc_monetary en_US.UTF-8
lc_numeric  en_US.UTF-8
lc_time en_US.UTF-8
listen_addresses    *
log_line_prefix %m [%p] %q%u@%d
log_timezone    localtime
max_connections 100
max_stack_depth 2MB
port    5432
search_path public
shared_buffers  512MB
ssl on
ssl_cert_file   /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
ssl_key_file    /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
stats_temp_directory    /var/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pg_stat_tmp
TimeZone    localtime
unix_socket_directories /var/run/postgresql
```

This runs on the server of 2Gb RAM with 2x2.4MHz CPU with Ubuntu x64.
The trouble is illustrated here:
[image: Postgres troubles illustration]
I wonder if Postgres able to handle so many requests. We tried to enlarge number of cores (requests to Postgre happens from different workers via different sessions). We tried to increase the server memory and shared_buffers parameter. None of these helps. I'd appreciate any opinions.

Comment: If you say 20000 per *second* I would raise an eyebrow. Try to find the statements that are slow and tune them. More memory wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I say 20000 per minute

Comment: Right, that shouldn't be a problem if the statements are simple and short.